Why isn't the conditional class binding applied after state update in Next.js?
I am working on a mega menu in React (Next.js). I fetch the menu items from an API endpoint with AJAX call, the menu items are displayed. The first step would be that if I click on one of the menu items, the other menu items disappear, and the sub-menu items of the clicked menu item appear instead. For now, I'm stuck on the fact that I can't remove the other menu items. I created a function that updates the state of "selectedItem" onClick event. So far it's fine, the state update is happening. However, the conditional class binding does not work, the "renderMenuItems" function does not receive the updated state and therefore the element does not receive the "selected" class. How do I remove the other menu items afterwards is another question.
'use client';

import { css, cx } from '@/styled-system/css';
import Image from 'next/image';
import MainMenuActions from './mainMenuActions';
import MainMenuSearch from './mainMenuSearch';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Hamburger from 'hamburger-react';
import IconSearchRegular from '@/components/icon/iconSearchRegular';
import IconChevronDownLight from '@/components/icon/iconChevronDownLight';
import { token } from '@/styled-system/tokens';

interface Props extends React.ComponentProps<'div'> {
  className?: string;
  topMenuIsOut: boolean;
}

interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  href: string;
  newPage: boolean;
  childrens: MenuItem | MenuItem[];
}

export default function MainMenuBottom(props: Props) {
  const { className, topMenuIsOut } = props;

  const [searchIsOpen, setSearchIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [hamburgerIsOpen, setHamburgerIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]); // Specify the type explicitly
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<MenuItem | null>(null);

  const handleMenuItemClick = (clickedItem: MenuItem) => {
    setSelectedItem(clickedItem);
  };

  const renderMenuItems = (items: MenuItem[], selectedItem: MenuItem | null) => {
    return items.map((item) => (
      <li
        onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(item)}
        className={`d-flex align-items-center ${selectedItem === item ? 'selected' : ''}`}
        key={item.href}
      >
        {item.title}
        <IconChevronDownLight size={8} color={token('colors.myYellow')} className={styles.bottomNavIcon} />
      </li>
    ));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://www.myapiurl.com')
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data: { 'main-menu': MenuItem[] }) => {
        const mainMenuItems = data['main-menu'];

        // Render main menu items
        setMenuItems(renderMenuItems(mainMenuItems, null));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.mainMenuBottom, className, 'container')}>
      {searchIsOpen && (
        <div className={styles.bottomSearch}>
          <MainMenuSearch width="100%" placeholder="Kezdj el gépelni..." onClose={() => setSearchIsOpen(!searchIsOpen)} />
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={cx(styles.bottomNavWrapper, !topMenuIsOut ? styles.bottomNavWrapperFloating : undefined)}>
        <div className={cx(styles.bottomNavLogo, !topMenuIsOut && !searchIsOpen ? styles.bottomNavLogoFloating : undefined)}>
        </div>

        <ul className={cx(styles.bottomNav, !topMenuIsOut ? styles.bottomNavFloating : undefined)}>
          {menuItems.length > 0 && menuItems} {/* Render the dynamic menu items only when menuItems is not empty */}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.bottomIcons}>
        <MainMenuActions />
        <div className={styles.bottomIconSearch} onClick={() => setSearchIsOpen(!searchIsOpen)}>
          <IconSearchRegular size={16} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.bottomIconHamburger}>
          <Hamburger size={26} toggled={hamburgerIsOpen} toggle={setHamburgerIsOpen} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I would be really grateful for any help. Thank you in advance.

You should never store rendered jsx in the state because it won't update

You should update menuItems, when an item is selected you use handleMenuItemClick, inside it you should use setMenuItems to the new sub menu items
